# Java swing error " 'void' type not allowed here "

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I'm getting an error *'void' type not allowed here*

**CODE:**

```
public void create(JPanel jp){
    jp.add(new JButton().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40)));        
}
```

But when I use the same code without `.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40))` it works fine.

**WORKING CODE**

```
public void create(JPanel jp){
    jp.add(new JButton());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`setPreferredSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)) "returns" a `void`, so it cannot be passed as a parameter to [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)). You'd have to break up the code and separate to several statements:

```
public void create(JPanel jp){
    JButton myButton = new JButton();
    myButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    jp.add(myButton);
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am not allowed to edit your answer but you have a duplicate `new` in there and the `setPreferredSize()` lacks a `;` in the end. Perhaps you can correct that.

Comment: @morido you weren't allowed to edit since chalitha had an inbound edit to apply these exact changes, which I just accepted. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

Internal code of `setPreferredSize` from here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29

```
public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {                    
  super.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
}
```

When you are trying to execute this code

```
jp.add(new JButton().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40)));
```

`new JButton().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40))` return void, Thats why you are getting this 'void' type not allowed here

When you trying to add only `new JButton()` then its working fine because you are adding instance of `JButton`.

Solution :

```
JButton myButton = new JButton();
myButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
jp.add(myButton);
```